# Dependence of run-time from task volume

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, process

I have to find out dependence of time to task volume. I have an array that elements are processed. 1082 elements are processed for 1.498 sec.; 2164 - 3.292 sec.; 4328 - 10.479 sec. As you can see it's nonlinear dependence. How do I find it? Processor has 2 cores.

Comment: How is the array accessed during this "processing"?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer while you did not post any source code. 
But timing looks like there are nested loops in your array processing. 
Do you have one outer and an inner loop? That might lead to your timings. And to the O^2 timing.

Comment: this is code:`dispatch_queue_t queue =dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0); dispatch_apply(count,queue , ^(size_t size) { [array addObject:@2]; NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; NSLog(@"Time, @%", date); });`